# Multiple queue consumers updating same resources

Tags: message-queue, amazon-sqs

I have a queue that receives "event" messages that cause the recalculation of one or more shared resource. The ordering of these messages are important within a specific resource, and the queue could contain multiple messages for the same resource at any one time.

I'd like to design the system in such a way that multiple consumers could be added (ie. to fan out) in the future without worrying about messages being processed out of order (again for the particular resource that they belong to)

I can think of several ways to work around the problem, including resource locks and bulk-processing outstanding messages per-resource, but my question is: is there an existing pattern or whitepaper that describes a solution to this problem?

The question is technology-agnostic, but I'll be using SQS.

Comment: Does the consumer have a way to determine if the messages are arriving out of order? For example, do the event messages contain a sequential identifier set by the producer?

Comment: @AdrianHofman - No the messages come from different consumers.

Comment: Ok, how does a consumer determine that it has received a message out of order?

Answer (score 0):

Your events will need some kind of sequence number per resource that allows the consumers to determine that when they have received a message out of order. A good reference for this is the [Message Sequence](http://www.eaipatterns.com/MessageSequence.html) pattern.

You will need some storage (e.g., a database) that is shared by the scaled out consumers, with the sequence number of the last processed message persisted there, so that each consumer has a consistent view of what the last processed message was. (You may already have some shared storage for your consumers for message deduplication and the domain data.)

With that in place, you have a few options:

- Implement a [Resequencer](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/Resequencer.html). This sounds like the "bulk-processing outstanding messages per-resource" idea that you mentioned in your question. A disadvantage of this pattern is that you may need to take extra care to make sure that the resequencer stores messages in a durable fashion. This could be more trouble than it's worth.
- I believe that a far simpler solution exists: If a consumer determines that it has received a message out of order, it simply doesn't process the message, and doesn't remove it from the queue. The message will not be received by a consumer again until the SQS visibility timeout expires. During that time, other messages in the sequence may be received and processed. Once the visibility timeout expires, the old message will then be available for processing again, at which point it could be the next message in the sequence. If not, it will simply be left in the queue until the next message in the sequence is processed.